# Map a CSV element to a list of strings using OpenCsv?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have a CSV file delimited by a single space character, like so-

```
<HEADING ROW>
a b c,d,e,f
m n o,p,q
```

Here, the last element is a list of strings concatenated with the comma separator. I'm currently using the **`OpenCsv`** library to parse this CSV file into a list of POJOs.

Here is my POJO definition:

```
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByName;

import java.util.List;

public class Foo {

    @CsvBindByName(column = "heading1", required = true)
    private Long first;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "heading2", required = true)
    private String third;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "heading3", required = true)
    private List<String> fourth;
}
```

So all the fields in this object are of different types, especially the last one, which is of a list type, and can be of any non-zero length.
Here's my code to map the CSV file to a list of these objects:

```
    public List<Foo> readCsvFromPath(final String filePath) throws IOException {
        try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(filePath));) {
            CsvToBean<Foo> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Foo>(reader)
                    .withSeparator(' ')
                    .withType(Foo.class)
                    .build();
            return csvToBean.parse();
        }
    }
```

What I'm not sure about here is how can the last element of the CSV file, ie, "c,d,e,f" or "o,p,q" will get respectively mapped to lists like `{"c", "d", "e", "f"}` and `{"o", "p", "q"}`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`@CsvBindAndSplitByName`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#custom_converters).

Replace this code

```java
@CsvBindByName(column = "heading3", required = true)
private List<String> fourth;
```

with

```java
@CsvBindAndSplitByName(column = "heading3", required = true, elementType = String.class, splitOn = ",")
private List<String> fourth;
```